# HTMLAudioElement con Ionic en android 8.1

Tags: android, angular, ionic

Tengo una app con Ionic4 que es básicamente un player, esta la desarrollé con HTMLAudioElement, pero al dar play en un equipo con android 8.1 me indica el siguiente error:

NotSupportedError: The element has no supported sources.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';

import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network/ngx';
import { Dialogs } from '@ionic-native/dialogs/ngx';

@Component({
selector: 'app-home',
templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage  {
audio: any;
subscribe: any;
 

constructor(
public platform: Platform,
public alertController: AlertController,
public network: Network,
public dialogs: Dialogs

) {
  this.subscribe = this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(10,()=>{
    console.log("this.subscribe: ",this.subscribe);
    this.confirmMessage();
  });
  
  this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(()=>{
    this.dialogs.alert('Se ha desconectado de internet','Radio SuperNova');
    this.exitApp();
  });

  if(this.network.type === 'none'){
    
    this.exitForInternet();}

  this.network.onConnect().subscribe(()=>{
    if(this.network.type !== 'wifi'){
      this.dialogs.alert('estás conectado a través de tu internet móvil, si puedes cámbiate a wifi para no consumir tus datos', 'Radio SuperNova');
    }
  });
}

ionViewWillEnter(){
  
}
ngOnInit(){

const play = document.getElementById('play');
const stop = document.getElementById('pause');
const loader = document.getElementById('loader');
const conect = this.network;
const dialog = this.dialogs;
const audio = new Audio();
const source = document.createElement('source');
source.setAttribute('src','http://104.131.18.232/proxy/supernova?mp=/stream')
// audio.src = 'http://104.131.18.232/proxy/supernova?mp=/stream';
audio.load();
audio.appendChild(source);
  play.style.display ="block";
  loader.style.display ="none";
  stop.style.display= "none";

  audio.addEventListener('playing',function(){
    loader.style.display ="none";
    play.style.display="none";
    stop.style.display="block";
  });

audio.addEventListener('waiting',function(){
  loader.style.display ="block";
  play.style.display="none";
  stop.style.display="none";
  
  const data = audio.play();
    audio.loop = true;
    data.then(function(i) {
      console.log("reproduce "+ i);

      // Automatic playback started!
      play.style.display = "none";
      stop.style.display = "block";
      loader.style.display = "none";
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log("reproduce error "+ error);
    });    
});

stop.addEventListener('click', function(){
   audio.pause();
    play.style.display = "block";
    stop.style.display = "none";
    loader.style.display = "none";
});

play.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(conect.type === 'none'){
      dialog.alert(
        'Radio SuperNova',
        'no estás conectado a internet', 
      );
      setTimeout(()=>{
        navigator["app"].exitApp();
      },2000)
  }else{
    // audio.loop = true;
    const data = audio.play();
    data.then(function(i) {
      // Automatic playback started!
      play.style.display = "none";
      stop.style.display = "block";
      loader.style.display = "none";
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log("reproduce error "+ error);
    });        
  }
});
}

async confirmMessage(){

const alert = await this.alertController.create({
header: 'Radio SuperNova',
message: 'estás seguro que deseas salir de la app?',
buttons: [
  {
    text: 'No',
    role: 'cancel',
    cssClass: 'secondary',
    handler: (blah) => {
    }
  }, {
    text: 'Acepto',
    handler: () => {
      this.exitApp();
    }
  }
]
 });
 await alert.present();
}

async exitForInternet(){
const alert = await this.alertController.create({
cssClass: 'my-custom-class',
header: 'Radio SuperNova',
message: 'no estás conectado a internet',
buttons: [
   {
    text: 'Acepto',
    handler: () => {
      this.exitApp();
    }
   }
  ]
  });
  await alert.present();
 }

exitApp(){
navigator["app"].exitApp();
}
 ngOnDestroy() {

  if(this.audio) {
  this.audio.pause();
  this.audio = null;
   }
  }
 }
```

Quedo muy agradecido de ante manos.

Answer (score 0):

Hola el problema que tienes es que no le has agregado fuentes para reproducir audio, lo que debes hacer es crear un elemento `<source>` que es en donde se define dicha información y no en la etiqueta `<audio>` como lo estas haciendo.

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var source = document.createElement('source');
source.setAttribute('src', 'http://104.131.18.232/proxy/supernova?mp=/stream');
video.load();
video.appendChild(source);
video.play();
```

Trata de adaptarla a tu ejemplo. Si tienes otros errores puedes dejarlo en los comentarios.

Comment: agradezco mucho tu respuesta, modificaré el código de la pregunta con los cambios que me sugieres, pero lamentablemente ahora me ocurre que la reproducción se detiene luego de unos 25 minutos, en la consola del android studio logré captar este dato en el log:

2020-07-06 23:00:59.805 10865-10964/io.ionic.starter D/AudioTrack: stop() called with 69807102 frames delivered

Comment: Creo que ese es un error que ya no es relacionado al sentido de la pregunta original, deberias considerar dejar la pregunta original y en una nueva pregunta probablemente atraigas más gente que pueda ayudarte incluyendome.

Comment: Te recomiendo dejar la pregunta original y marcar esta como correcta si te ayudó con el error que tenias, así los que tengan el mismo problema les podrá ser útil la información.